# Exclude a follower from copying an activity

Tags: getstream-io

Is it possible to exclude some followers when adding an activity?

Let's say `user:2`, `user:3`, `user:4` follow `user:1`.

When any activity is added on `user:1` feed, its copied into all it's followers feed *(that' right, I know it)*.

But, if I want to exclude `user:4` from copying the activity while keeping him the follower of `user:1` *(only in some special cases)*. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, our fan-out will always go to all followers when `user:1` inserts their activity.

A work-around you could build, though, would be to allow the activity to fan-out to `user:4`, but then issue a delete on the activity in `user:4`'s feed. This won't delete the activity everywhere else, only in `user:4`'s feed.

Keep in mind that if you do these API calls back-to-back in your software, the fan-out may not yet be completed to `user:4`'s feed, so the delete might silently fail.

As a side note, if you were to delete it from `user:1`'s feed where the activity originated, it *would* fan-out that delete and remove that record everywhere else.

Comment: That is a good work-around. I know fanout takes time, but after how much time I should request for `delete` as a safe side?

Comment: The fan-out speed will depend on the plan you're on. Our free tier may take a few seconds to fan-out, and priority is given for paid plans, and the higher tiered paid plans have much lower latencies on fan-out. A safe bet is probably 30 seconds. If you pull `user:4`'s feed in the meantime, you can always have a cached list of activities to exclude for that user which you can invalidate later once you no longer see those activity ID's in the feed.